# CollectionView, DataBinding, MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin

Hi everyone,

I am trying to implement MVVM in my application but i am failing to load data. 
I have a main page and it works fine, but once I want to navigate to the detail of my Ad and then the detail page is blank. There are my controls so i know that the pages is loaded just my data are missing. I cant seem to figure out where i have made  the mistake. I am new to coding so i sometimes tend to make very silly mistakes. I been trying to solve this for past few hours otherwise would not post it over here. Thank you of any opinion.

```
My HomePage 

<Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,25,0,0">
                    <CollectionView x:Name="ads"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding AdLogEntries}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HomePageTemplate}"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAd, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged"
                        Margin="12,0">
                     </CollectionView>
                </Grid>


public partial class HomePage : ContentPage

    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new HomePage ViewModel();
        }
        async  void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedAd = (AdLogEntry)e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault();
            if (selectedAd != null)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new AdDetail(selectedAd));
            }
        }
    }

namespace Baltazar.ViewModel

{
    public class HomePageViewModel : BaseViewModel

    {

        ObservableCollection<AdLogEntry> _adLogEntries;
        public ObservableCollection<AdLogEntry> AdLogEntries { get => _adLogEntries; set { _adLogEntries = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
        public AdLogEntry selectedAd;
        public HomePageViewModel()
        {
            AdLogEntries = new ObservableCollection<AdLogEntry>()


            {
                new AdLogEntry (){Id = 0, Image = "cat.jpg", Name = "Kocka" , Description = "seda kocka na prodej, mayliva, hrava, spolecenska " ,Price = 120, },
                new AdLogEntry (){Id = 1, Image = "cat2.jpg", Name = "Kocka", Description = "seda kocka na prodej, mayliva, hrava, spolecenska " ,Price = 120, },
                new AdLogEntry (){Id = 2, Image = "bobtailjpg.jpg", Name = "Kocka",Description = "seda kocka na prodej, mayliva, hrava, spolecenska ", Price = 120, },
            };

        }
    }
}
//Detail
 public class AdDetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        AdLogEntry _adDetail;

        public AdLogEntry AdDetail { get => _adDetail;set { _adDetail = value;OnPropertyChanged(); } }

        public AdDetailViewModel(AdLogEntry adDetail)
        {
            AdDetail = adDetail;
        }

    }
 public partial class AdDetail : ContentPage


    {
        //private AdLogEntry selectedAd;

        public AdDetail(AdLogEntry adDetail)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new AdDetailViewModel(adDetail);
        }


    }


//BaseViewModel
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged

    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

        protected BaseViewModel()
        {

        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="300" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ffimageloading:CachedImage
      x:Name="HeaderView"
      Grid.Row="0"
      Grid.RowSpan="2"
      Aspect="AspectFill"
      Source="{Binding AdLogEntries.Image}"/>
        <controls:Parallax Control
      x:Name="Parallax"
      Grid.Row="0"
      Grid.RowSpan="3">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="300" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <yummy:Pancake View
          Grid.Row="1"
          CornerRadius="24, 24, 0, 0"
          BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}"
          Margin="0, 20, 0, 0">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!-- Animal NAME -->
                        <Label
              Grid.Row="0"
              Text="{Binding AdLogEntries.Name}"
              />
                        <!-- QUANTITY -->
                        <Grid
              Grid.Row="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label
                Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding AdLogEntries.Price, StringFormat='{0:C0}'}"
                />
                        </Grid>
                        <!-- ABOUT -->
                        <Label
              Grid.Row="2"
              Text="Popis"
              />
                        <!-- DESCRIPTION -->
                        <Label
              Grid.Row="3"
              Text="{Binding AdLogEntries.Description}"
              />
                        <Grid
              Grid.Row="4"
              Margin="0, 12">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                      <!-- BUY NOW BUTTON -->
                            <yummy:PancakeView
                Grid.Column="1"
                HeightRequest="48"
                CornerRadius="24, 0, 24, 0"
                Background Color="Accent"
                Margin="24, 0, 0, 0">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Text="Buy now"
                    />
                                    <Label
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Text=">"
                    />
                                </Grid>
                            </yummy:Pancake View>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </yummy:Pancake View>
            </Grid>
        </controls:Parallax Control>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: post the XAML for AdDetail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SelectedItem never changes because you are not trigger OnPropertyChange. You can change your view model logic like this:

```
   private AdLogEntry selectedAd;
   public AdLogEntry SelectedAd { get => selectedAd; set { selectedAd = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAd"); } }
   public ICommand AdSelectionChangedCommand => new Command(AdSelectionChanged);

    private void AdSelectionChanged()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAd");
        Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DetailPage(SelectedAd));
    }
```

And in your XAML:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="ads"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding AdLogEntries}"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding AdSelectionChangedCommand}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAd, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        Margin="12,0">
```

Your detail page:

```
 public DetailPage(AdLogEntry detail)
 {
        this.BindingContext = new AdDetailViewModel(adDetail);
        InitializeComponent();
 }
```

In Detail XAML:

```
   <Label Text="{Binding AdDetail.Name}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

your `BindingContext` is `AdDetailViewModel`

```
BindingContext = new AdDetailViewModel(adDetail);
```

and your binding paths are like

```
<Label Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding AdLogEntries.Description}"
```

`AdDetailViewModel` does not have a `AdLogEntries` property.  It does have a `AdDetail`, so presumably you should use this as a binding path

```
<Label Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding AdDetail.Description}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your detail page XAML. To be precise, the problem is in your XAML Binding Expressions. All the bindings in the detail page has wrong path set. For example, for image control it should be `Source="{Binding AdDetail.Image}"` instead of `Source="{Binding AdLogEntries.Image}"`. It happens all the time and you catch these kind of errors in the output log when you debug the application.